# Reduce time for update query in Laravel (without for loop, for same key and multiple values)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
    ls_player_details::where('Bib_no', $ids[$i])->update(['chestno' => $chestnos[$i]]);
}
```

This update query takes 8secs for 162 records, so want to reduce the time

**So i made this one;**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($chestnos); $i++) {
    $data[] = array('chestno' => $chestnos[$i]);
}

ls_player_details::whereIn('Bib_no', $ids)->update($data);
```

**now what's the problem is;**

now i getting **data** like this

```
[ 
    {
        "chestno": 50
    },
    {
        "chestno": 51
    },
    {
        "chestno": 52
    },
    {
        "chestno": 53
    },
    {
        "chestno": 54
    },
    {
        "chestno": 55
    },
]
```

**But i want to get array like;**

```
["chestno": 50,"chestno": 50,"chestno": 50]
```

**problem:**

Pushing multiple values for same key in to array using for loop,

And i want to know there is any other method to done the same thing.

Comment: Although I don't think I know the answer to your question, I do have a helpful tip to improve your speed even more. Place `count($ids)` and `count($chestnos)` outside your for-loops in a separate variable. This way your program does not need to calculate/count every iteration in the for-loop.

Comment: what's the number 50 is?

Comment: sorry this is typo: ["chestno": 50,"chestno": 50,"chestno": 50] want to get value like ["chestno": 50,"chestno": 51,"chestno": 52] values are come from forloop iteration    $chestnos it's an array @InzamamIdrees

Comment: The same associative key name cannot be assigned more than once in a single-dimensional array, In addition the `wherein` would update all of the records to the `key-value`. ie. `UPDATE table SET a = 50, a = 51 WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2`  So your approach would not work either. To execute in a single query, you would need to refactor to a `CASE WHEN THEN ` or an `UPDATE JOIN` query using a temporary table holding the values to JOIN on.

Comment: Thank you :-) for your tip it reduced 0.891 seconds @Virginia

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, one method is to refactor using a `CASE WHEN` clause.

You should be able to use a [`DB:raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) select statement with your `update` method call.

```
$data = '(SELECT CASE Bib_no';
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $chestnos)) {
        /* uncomment to prevent NULL value when $id is not in $chestnos
        unset($ids[$i]);
        */
        continue;
    }
    $data .= ' WHEN "' . $id . '" THEN "' . $chestnos[$i] . '"';
}
$data .= ' END)';

ls_player_details::whereIn('Bib_no', $ids)
    ->update(['chestno' => DB::raw($data)]);
```

### Example https://3v4l.org/tglaB

The resulting query executed should look like:

```
UPDATE ls_player_details
SET chestno = (SELECT CASE Bib_no
WHEN "a" THEN "50"
WHEN "b" THEN "51"
WHEN "c" THEN "52"
WHEN "d" THEN "53"
WHEN "e" THEN "54"
WHEN "f" THEN "55"
WHEN "g" THEN "56"
END)
WHERE Bib_no IN("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
```

This will update the `chestno` column to the corresponding `Bib_no` reference if it is selected. If there are no `Bib_no` matches in the `CASE WHEN` clause, it will default to `NULL`.

Comment: Great...! Thank you so much...! it's working...! :-) :-) :-) @fyrye

Comment: @NagarajanR How much time it takes now, the update query? just curious.

Comment: Less than 200ms :-) @Learner